# dropna remove all rows with valid values and only NA rows are left in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to clean np values in an open sourced data.

I am using python3, Jupyter and pandas.

```
 response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://resources.lendingclub.com/LoanStats3c.csv.zip')
 import shutil
 url = 'https://resources.lendingclub.com/LoanStats3c.csv.zip'
 file_name = 'LoanStats3c.csv.zip'

 with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
     shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
     with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
         zf.extractall()

 loan=pd.read_csv(open('LoanStats3c.csv'), skiprows=1, parse_dates=True, index_col='id') 
 loan.describe()

 # remove all columns with all NAs
 loan = loan.dropna(axis=1, how = 'all')
 loan.describe()

 # remove all rows with any NAs
 loan = loan.dropna(axis = 0)

 loan.describe()
```

But, the results are all columns with all NAs:

```
  loan_amnt  funded_amnt  funded_amnt_inv  installment  annual_inc  dti  \
  count        0.0          0.0              0.0          0.0         0.0  0.0   
  mean         NaN          NaN              NaN          NaN         NaN  NaN    
  std          NaN          NaN              NaN          NaN         NaN  NaN   
  min          NaN          NaN              NaN          NaN         NaN  NaN   
  25%          NaN          NaN              NaN          NaN         NaN  NaN   
  50%          NaN          NaN              NaN          NaN         NaN  NaN   
  75%          NaN          NaN              NaN          NaN         NaN  NaN   
  max          NaN          NaN              NaN          NaN         NaN  NaN
```

Why all rows with valid values are gone and only the NA columns are left ?

thanks

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

When you'r using .dropna() like that all ocurrences with NaN values are deleted from dataframe

```
loan.dropna(axis=1, how = 'all')
```

Will delete the columns with all values in NaN

```
loan.dropna(axis = 0)
```

Will delete the rows with a least one value in NaN

I saw the file and i'm pretty sure that every rows has at least one column in NaN

Finally when using *.describe()* the dataframe is empty and the values that are shown are a descriptive statistics of that, if you want to see the real DF use print(df) or in jupyter just let the variable at the end of the block

```
some code
some code
some code 
variable = pd.DataFrame([])

#print(variable)
variable
```

That would show you the value of the variable